# При считывании c помощью fread в буфер попадают лишние символы

Tags: c

```
#define BUFF_SIZE (1000)

while (1)
{
    if (len == 0)   //Начинаем считывание, изначально длина = 0
    {
        len = fread(BUFF, 1, BUFF_SIZE,
                    F); /*Записано, что считано 1000 символов, но в BUFF[997] - BUFF[999] - символы, которых нет в файле. Следующее считывание начинает как раз с 998-го символа файла. Т.е., между ними внезапно возникли 3 лишних символа*/

        if (len == 0)
            break;

        str = BUFF;
    }

    c = *str; //Единственное обращение к буферу, далее идёт работа с 'c'
    ++str;
    len--;

    if (node - CHILD[c] != NULL)
    {
        node = node->CHILD[c];
        k = node->code;
    }
    else
    {
        print(k, O) //O - указатель на выходной файл
        node->CHILD[c] = new_node();
        node->CHILD[c]->code = t
                               t++;
        node = root->CHILD[c];
        k = node->code;
    }
```

После выполнения этой команды len становится равным 1000, но позиция в файле - 997; три последних символа в конце BUFF берутся непонятно откуда. Причём, это происходит стабильно на первой итерации цикла, в котором находится эта команда, на остальных же - по-разному. С чем может быть связано появление такой ситуации? Как от этого избавиться?

- Идёт работа не с текстовым файлом, а побитово считывается файл BMP-изображения
- Как видно из приведённого выше отрывка кода больше к буферу обращений нет. Его [кода] больше, но он ещё менее удовлетворяет теме

ЯП Си

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42324/discussion-on-question-by-----c--fread---).

Answer (score 1):

У проблемы нашлось весьма банальное, но, как по мне, неочевидное решение. Вся суть была скрыта в `str++` - по непонятным причинам там, всё же, мог произойти сдвиг на несколько байт в то время, как `len--` спокойно отнимал единичку от длины и мы получали выход за пределы массива BUFF. Да, всё же разумнее было использовать индексы для навигации по BUFF. Да, я признаю свои ошибки и хочу сказать спасибо всем, кто пытался помочь.

И, собственно, само решение: вместо внешней проверки `if (len == 0)` я воспользовался адресной арифметикой: `if (str - BUFF >= BUFF_SIZE)`

Comment: Ничего не объясняющие танцы с бубном.

Comment: Не объясняет, т.к. если `char *str;`, то `str++` **всегда** добавит 1! / Показывайте, как конкретно получали  -- `"... len становится равным 1000, но позиция в файле - 997; три последних символа в конце BUFF берутся непонятно откуда"`

Comment: Вангую проблемы в автоконвертации между `\r\n` и `\n`. Откройте файл в бинарном режиме.

Comment: @VladD, ТС в своих комментариях уверял, что пишет `fopen(..., "rb");` / В чем-то Вы, наверное, правы. Вангую, что прочитано 1000, а смотрел он файл в каком нибудь редакторе, который считает `\r\n` за один символ.

Comment: @avp: Ага, или так. Дождёмся компилируемого примера, да.